# JWT encryption is normal?

Tags: web, oauth, jwe

I'm starting with the JWT, and I did a decryption test of my token on base64 and I actually decrypt it, except for the Signature part that I don't decipher it, my question is: is the JWT token normal to decrypt it? and if it's normal how I can prevent this.

I'am using algorithm HS256

thanksgiving

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you have is not an encrypted token (**JWE** => [RFC7516](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7516)) but a signed token (**JWS** => [RFC7515](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515)).

The algorithm HS256 is a **signature algorithm** referenced in the [RFC7518 section 3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7518#section-3.2).

With signed tokens, the payload is not encrypted but only encoded using the Base 64 Url Safe data encoding (see [RFC4648](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648)).